CORS error in Blockstream Esplora docker container even with `CORS_ALLOW=*`
I am running Esplora via this command
docker run --name esplora-container -p 50001:50001 -p 8094:80 --volume $PWD/data_bitcoin_regtest:/data -e CORS_ALLOW=* --rm -i -t blockstream/esplora bash -c "/srv/explorer/run.sh bitcoin-regtest explorer"

but I am getting the error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8094/regtest/api/address/bcrt1pw4egam6splawuqt6djwex5x7kxenwezwcu60plt28fenmqe8zn3q9t0evs/utxo. (Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed). Status code: 404.

Why is this happening since I am passing the CORS_ALLOW=* env var ?
